# Collision of multiple fluid flows at a point

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I would like to do an analysis when two or more fluid streams flowing from different direction with different velocity, meet at a point. What happen after the collision? Are there any related studies or papers?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvRg9NuO9Oc it seems like the key phrase to google for is "impinging fluid jet"